# Docker does not auto update DNS server details in /etc/resolv.conf

Tags: docker, boot2docker

I am using Docker version 1.9 and when I switch on VPN my local machines `/etc/resolv.conf` gets updated with new DNS servers.

However this does not get automatically updated in /etc/resolv.conf inside the container.

According to the documentation it should. Any solutions?

I am using a El Capitan Mac OSX.

Documentation about this: https://docs.docker.com/v1.8/articles/networking/#dns

Comment: Docker cannot be expected to auto detect VPN networks. Have you tried explicitly setting the DNS server using the "--dns" parameter?

Comment: Its not supposed to auto detect changes, but according to the docs _Containers which are running when the host configuration changes will need to stop and start to pick up the host changes due to lack of a facility to ensure atomic writes of the resolv.conf file while the container is running._ Even stopping/starting the container this doesnt update the resolv.conf content